# How to set a ceil value only for minValue

Tags: angularjs, rangeslider

I'm using a rangeSlider with this specific html configuration :

[The rangeSlider preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4bgi.png)

[image]

```
<rzslider data-rz-slider-model="rangeSlider.minValue"
          data-rz-slider-high="rangeSlider.maxValue"
          data-rz-slider-options="rangeSlider.options">
</rzslider>
```

and this angularjs configuration :

```
$scope.rangeSlider = 
{
    minValue: startTime,
    maxValue: endTime,
    options: 
    {
        floor: 0,
        ceil: 36,
        step: 1,
        noSwitching: true,
        minRange: 1,
        maxRange: 24,
        showSelectionBar: true,
    }
};
```

Everything works great but I want to prevent ONLY for the rangeSlider.minValue to exceed the value 23 and I can't succeed in doing that.

Do you have any idea to dealing with that or is it simply possible?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a handler for the built in `onEnd` event for `rzSlider`. Add this to your `options`:

```
options: {
    // your existing options settings go here
    onEnd: function() {
        if ($scope.rangeSlider.minValue > 23) {
            $scope.rangeSlider.minValue = 23;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a good solution thank you, I did not think about it but if possible I'd prefer to prevent the drag instead of "reset" I don't know if it's clear

Comment: It doesn't look like that is possible with this directive. The best you could probably do is use the `onChange` event, but that still won't prevent a user from dragging quickly and exceeding your desired `minValue`.

Comment: Ok it's too bad. I'm gonna use your solution, thanks a lot !